# Access helper module class in Sinatra from routes

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm writing a modular [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com) application. I have written a [helper module](https://github.com/atmosx/pritory/blob/master/helpers/skroutz.rb) to handle oauth calls.

Now I'm using a [global variable](https://github.com/atmosx/pritory/blob/2646d448c1c7c0d801f583c3577af8fa96142ef0/routes/skroutz.rb#L10) (e.g. `$squick ||= Skroutz::Query.new`) to create the object, which is shared through my routes (see [here](https://github.com/atmosx/pritory/blob/2646d448c1c7c0d801f583c3577af8fa96142ef0/routes/skroutz.rb) ).

Then [J. Hass](http://jhass.eu/) mentioned that I should avoid using global variables because is not thread-safe and he is probably right.

However, I don't know how to create an instance of this class, accessible through all my routes. I've tried a couple of things but nothing worked. I'm sure it can be done in multiple ways though.

Thanks

ps. Please be descriptive, it's important for me to understand what I'm doing :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to: http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html, you can do this:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

module Animals
  class Dog
  end
end

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  set :dog, Animals::Dog.new

  get '/' do
    puts "The object_id in '/' is: #{settings.dog.object_id}"
  end

  get '/val' do
    "The object_id in '/val' is: #{settings.dog.object_id}"
  end

  run! if app_file == $0
end
```

If you enter the following url in your browser:

```
http://localhost:4567/
```

...then enter this url in your browser:

```
http://localhost:4567/val
```

...then check the id that is output in the server window, it will be the same id that is displayed on the web page.

However, I don't know if the settings object is thread safe.  According to the Sinatra README:

> **Request/Instance Scope**
>
> For every incoming request, a new instance of your application class
>   is created, and all handler blocks run in that scope.

But the results above show that the second request is able to access the same Dog object as the first request, which means the second request can change the Dog object that the first request sees.  Whether one request can change the Dog object at the same time another request is reading the Dog object is not clear from the docs or my google searches.

Comment: @atmosx, You probably shouldn't accept my answer because I don't know if it's thread safe.  Give other people some time to respond.

Comment: okay, thanks for the pointer. Just tried your approach, unfortunately it's not possible to access the object because I'm loading the helpers in the end: https://github.com/atmosx/pritory/blob/master/pritory.rb but you gave me an idea, although now very elegant. :-)

Comment: @atmosx, What's the reason for having the require's at the end of your code and not at the top of the file?

Comment: I thought that was kind of necessary evil. Remember that I had an issue in the past, using the same skeleton, but it's not true. Just tried and works. My bad :-)

Comment: @atmosx, A `require`(or `require_relative`) executes the code in a file, so you do have to be careful that the code in the required file doesn't depend on some other code coming before it, e.g.if the required file mentions MyApp, then the require must come after the definition of MyApp. However, if something in your code needs to create an instance of some class, e.g. Dog, then the Dog class has to be defined first, so you are going to have to put the require for the Dog class ahead of the code that wants to create a Dog instance.